# В массив элементов добавить элемент, созданный с помощью createElement

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Я написал на JavaScript функции добавления и удаления элементов на странице, но я очень часто обращаюсь к документу, пример:

`task = document.querySelectorAll('.task')`

И также я в любой ситуации получаю все данные из массива элементов, которые я получил через `querySelector`. Могу ли я в такой массив, через который я выбрал элементы, добавить элемент, созданный с помощью `createElement`?

Я очень не хочу лишний раз обращаться к `document`, хочу писать качественный код, поэтому меня это интересует, а сам не понимаю как это написать.

```js
let task, tasks, task__close;
let add__button = document.querySelector('.add__button');
let add__input = document.querySelector('.add__input');
let arr = [];
tasks = document.querySelector('.tasks');
task = document.querySelectorAll('.task');

function addElem() {
  if (add__input.value === '') {
    return false;
  }
  let block = document.createElement('div');
  task = document.querySelectorAll('.task');
  block.className = 'task';
  arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < task.length; i++) {
    arr.unshift(task[i].getAttribute('data-id'));
  }
  arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });
  let num = addNext(arr);

  block.setAttribute('data-id', num);
  block.setAttribute('data-listener', false);
  block.innerHTML = '<div class="task__close"></div>';
  block.innerHTML += add__input.value;
  tasks.prepend(block);
  add__input.value = '';
  task__close = document.querySelector('.task__close');
  task = document.querySelectorAll('.task');
  startClose();
} // function addElem()

function startClose() {
  task__close = document.querySelectorAll('.task__close');
  for (let i = 0; i < task.length; i++) {
    if (task[i].getAttribute('data-listener') == 'false') {
      task__close[i].addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.path[1].remove();
      });
      task[i].setAttribute('data-listener', true);
    }
  }
} // function startClose()

add__button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  addElem();
});

add__input.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  if (event.code == 'Enter' || event.keyCode == '13' || event.key == 'Enter') {
    addElem();
  }
});

startClose();

function addNext(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] != i) {
      arr.splice(i, 0, i);
      return i;
    }
  }
  arr.push(arr.length);
  return arr.length - 1;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700&display=swap');
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
ul {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1100px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container.fluid {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.spheres {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.sphere {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.sphere:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.sphere .svg__icon {
  max-width: 70px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.sphere .svg__icon img {
  width: 100%;
}

.sphere__title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.add {
  background-color: #46a049;
  padding: 25px 0;
}

.add__title {
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.add__input-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 10px auto 0;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.add__input {
  outline: 0;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  border: 1px solid white;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 7px 55px 7px 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.add__button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 15px;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.add__button:before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-40%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #91a8c4;
  height: 20px;
  right: 40%;
}

.add__button:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-40%, -50%);
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #91a8c4;
  height: 20px;
  right: 40%;
}

.add__button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.add__button:hover:before {
  background-color: #3675bc;
}

.add__button:hover:after {
  background-color: #3675bc;
}

.tasks {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.task {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.task__close {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 15.5px;
  position: relative;
}

.task__close:before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  right: 6px;
  top: 3px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.8);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.8);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .2s linear opacity;
}

.task__close:hover {
  background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.task__close:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <section class="section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="spheres">
        <div class="sphere health">
          <div class="svg__icon">
            <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/148/148838.svg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="sphere__title">
            Здоровье
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sphere intelligence">
          <div class="svg__icon">
            <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1491/1491214.svg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="sphere__title">
            Развитие
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sphere sociality">
          <div class="svg__icon">
            <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1078/1078011.svg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="sphere__title">
            Отношения
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- .spheres -->
    </div>
    <!-- .container -->

    <div class="container fluid">
      <div class="add">
        <div class="add__title">
          Добавить задачу
        </div>
        <div class="add__input-wrapper">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Бег 1 км" class="add__input">
          <div class="add__button"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- .container.fluid -->

    <div class="container">
      <div class="tasks">
        <div class="task" data-id="0" data-listener='false'>
          <div class="task__close"></div>
          Моя первая задача
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- .container -->

  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `... часто обращаюсь к документу ...` - не побойтесь воспользоваться единожды объявлением `const`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Предлагаю для начала преобразовать task в обычный массив, далее потом при создании нового блока task мы добавляем его в массив, методом push и сразу же цепляем обработчик закрытия task на task__close, избегая лишний раз вызова функции startClose()

```js
let task, tasks, task__close;
let add__button = document.querySelector('.add__button');
let add__input = document.querySelector('.add__input');
let arr = [];
tasks = document.querySelector('.tasks');
task = [...document.querySelectorAll('.task')];

function addElem() {
 if (add__input.value === '') {
  return false;
 }
 let block = document.createElement('div');
 block.className = 'task';
 arr = [];
 for (let i = 0; i < task.length; i++) {
  arr.unshift(task[i].getAttribute('data-id'));
 }
 arr.sort(function(a,b){ 
  return a - b;
 });
 let num = addNext(arr);

 block.setAttribute('data-id', num);
 block.setAttribute('data-listener', false);
 block.innerHTML = '<div class="task__close"></div>';
 block.innerHTML += add__input.value;
    task.push(block);
 tasks.prepend(block);
 add__input.value = '';
  block.querySelector('.task__close').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.path[1].remove();
   });
 //task__close = document.querySelector('.task__close');
 //startClose();
} // function addElem()

function startClose() {
 task__close = document.querySelectorAll('.task__close');
 for (let i = 0; i < task.length; i++) {
  if (task[i].getAttribute('data-listener') == 'false') {
   task__close[i].addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.path[1].remove();
   });
   task[i].setAttribute('data-listener', true);
  }
 }
} // function startClose()

add__button.addEventListener('click', () => {
 addElem();
});

add__input.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
 if (event.code == 'Enter' || event.keyCode == '13' || event.key == 'Enter') {
  addElem();
 }
});

startClose();

function addNext(arr) {
 for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     if (arr[i] != i) {
   arr.splice(i, 0, i);
   return i;
     }
  }
 arr.push(arr.length);
 return arr.length - 1;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700&display=swap');

*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 color: black;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ul {
 margin: 0;
}

ul {
 list-style: none;
}

img {
 display: block;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

.container {
 max-width: 1100px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.container.fluid {
 max-width: 100%; 
}

.spheres {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
}

.sphere {
 border-right: 1px solid black;
 flex-grow: 1;
 padding: 15px 0;
}

.sphere:first-child {
 border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.sphere  .svg__icon {
 max-width: 70px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.sphere  .svg__icon img {
 width: 100%;
}

.sphere__title {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 10px;
 font-size: 20px;
}

.add {
 background-color: #46a049;
 padding: 25px 0;
}

.add__title {
 font-size: 22px;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
}

.add__input-wrapper {
 position: relative;
 max-width: 500px;
 margin: 10px auto 0;
 padding: 0 15px;
}

.add__input {
 outline: 0;
 font-family: inherit;
 font-size: inherit;
 border: 1px solid white;
 display: block;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 7px 55px 7px 20px;
 width: 100%;
}

.add__button {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 right:15px;
 transform: translate(0, -50%);
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
}

.add__button:before {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 content: '';
 top: 50%;
 transform: translate(-40%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
 width: 2px;
 background-color: #91a8c4;
 height: 20px;
 right: 40%;
}

.add__button:after {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 content: '';
 top: 50%;
 transform: translate(-40%, -50%);
 width: 2px;
 background-color: #91a8c4;
 height: 20px;
 right: 40%;
}

.add__button:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
}

.add__button:hover:before {
 background-color: #3675bc;
}

.add__button:hover:after {
 background-color: #3675bc;
}

.tasks {
 margin-top: 20px;
 padding: 0 20px;
}

.task {
 position: relative;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
 padding: 10px 0;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
}

.task__close {
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 border: 1px solid gray;
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin-right: 15.5px;
 position: relative;
}

.task__close:before {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 content: '';
 right: 6px;
 top: 3px;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 width: 5px;
 height: 10px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(128,128,128,0.8);
 border-right: 1px solid rgba(128,128,128,0.8);
 opacity: 0;
 transition: .2s linear opacity;
}

.task__close:hover {
 background-color: rgba(128,128,128,0.2);
 cursor: pointer;
}

.task__close:hover:before {
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

 <section class="section">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="spheres">
    <div class="sphere health">
     <div class="svg__icon">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/148/148838.svg" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="sphere__title">
      Здоровье
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sphere intelligence">
     <div class="svg__icon">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1491/1491214.svg" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="sphere__title">
      Развитие
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sphere sociality">
     <div class="svg__icon">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1078/1078011.svg" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="sphere__title">
      Отношения
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>  <!-- .spheres -->
  </div> <!-- .container -->

  <div class="container fluid">
   <div class="add">
    <div class="add__title">
     Добавить задачу
    </div>
    <div class="add__input-wrapper">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Бег 1 км" class="add__input">
     <div class="add__button"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> <!-- .container.fluid -->

  <div class="container">
   <div class="tasks">
    <div class="task" data-id="0" data-listener='false'>
     <div class="task__close"></div>
     Моя первая задача
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> <!-- .container -->
 
 </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Не знаю, у меня ничего нихрена не получается. Я должен id нормально каждому элементу присваивать, чтобы при добавлении его id был 0,1,2,3,4 Если удалить, например, 2 элемент. То у элементов будет id 0,1,3,4, плюс у каждого элемента `.task__close` должен быть слушатель `oncliick` для удаления элемента, причём слушатель нужно задавать только один раз, поэтому я добавил к элементам id `data-listener`. А всё это я добавлял для того,чтобы потом всю информацию о добавлении и удалении добавлять в `localStorage`. Не получилось адаптировать новый код, для работы с `localStorage`,подскажите,как сделать?

Comment: боже, я просто из массива элементов не удалял элементы при удалении

Answer (score 1):

Я сделал код, который правильно выставляет `data-id` элементам `.task`, правда при удалении элемента, `data-id` как-то случайно проставляются, но работает всё правильно.

```js
let task, tasks, task__close;
let add__button = document.querySelector('.add__button');
let add__input = document.querySelector('.add__input');
let arr = [];
tasks = document.querySelector('.tasks');
task = [...tasks.querySelectorAll('.task')];

function addElem() {
 if (add__input.value === '') {
  return false;
 }
 let block = document.createElement('div');
 block.className = 'task';
 arr = [];
 for (let i = 0; i < task.length; i++) {
  arr.unshift(task[i].getAttribute('data-id'));
 }
 arr.sort(function(a,b){
  return a - b;
 });
 let num = addNext(arr);

 block.setAttribute('data-id', num);
 block.setAttribute('data-listener', false);
 block.innerHTML = '<div class="task__close"></div>';
 block.innerHTML += add__input.value;
 task.unshift(block);
 tasks.prepend(block);
 add__input.value = '';
 startClose();
} // function addElem()

function startClose() {
 task__close = tasks.querySelectorAll('.task__close');
 for (let i = 0; i < task.length; i++) {
  if (task[i].getAttribute('data-listener') == 'false') {
   task__close[i].addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    let id = event.path[1].getAttribute('data-id');
    task.splice(id, 1);
    for (let i = 0; i < task.length; i++) {
     task[i].setAttribute('data-id', i);
    }
    event.path[1].remove();
   });
   task[i].setAttribute('data-listener', true);
  }
 }
} // function startClose()

add__button.addEventListener('click', () => {
 addElem();
});

add__input.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
 if (event.code == 'Enter' || event.keyCode == '13' || event.key == 'Enter') {
  addElem();
 }
});

startClose();

function addNext(arr) {
 for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     if (arr[i] != i) {
   arr.splice(i, 0, i);
   return i;
     }
  }
 arr.push(arr.length);
 return arr.length - 1;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700&display=swap');

*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 color: black;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ul {
 margin: 0;
}

ul {
 list-style: none;
}

img {
 display: block;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

.container {
 max-width: 1100px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.container.fluid {
 max-width: 100%; 
}

.spheres {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
}

.sphere {
 border-right: 1px solid black;
 flex-grow: 1;
 padding: 15px 0;
}

.sphere:first-child {
 border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.sphere  .svg__icon {
 max-width: 70px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.sphere  .svg__icon img {
 width: 100%;
}

.sphere__title {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 10px;
 font-size: 20px;
}

.add {
 background-color: #46a049;
 padding: 25px 0;
}

.add__title {
 font-size: 22px;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
}

.add__input-wrapper {
 position: relative;
 max-width: 500px;
 margin: 10px auto 0;
 padding: 0 15px;
}

.add__input {
 outline: 0;
 font-family: inherit;
 font-size: inherit;
 border: 1px solid white;
 display: block;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 7px 55px 7px 20px;
 width: 100%;
}

.add__button {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 right:15px;
 transform: translate(0, -50%);
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
}

.add__button:before {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 content: '';
 top: 50%;
 transform: translate(-40%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
 width: 2px;
 background-color: #91a8c4;
 height: 20px;
 right: 40%;
}

.add__button:after {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 content: '';
 top: 50%;
 transform: translate(-40%, -50%);
 width: 2px;
 background-color: #91a8c4;
 height: 20px;
 right: 40%;
}

.add__button:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
}

.add__button:hover:before {
 background-color: #3675bc;
}

.add__button:hover:after {
 background-color: #3675bc;
}

.tasks {
 margin-top: 20px;
 padding: 0 20px;
}

.task {
 position: relative;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
 padding: 10px 0;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
}

.task__close {
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 border: 1px solid gray;
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin-right: 15.5px;
 position: relative;
}

.task__close:before {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 content: '';
 right: 6px;
 top: 3px;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 width: 5px;
 height: 10px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(128,128,128,0.8);
 border-right: 1px solid rgba(128,128,128,0.8);
 opacity: 0;
 transition: .2s linear opacity;
}

.task__close:hover {
 background-color: rgba(128,128,128,0.2);
 cursor: pointer;
}

.task__close:hover:before {
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

 <section class="section">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="spheres">
    <div class="sphere health">
     <div class="svg__icon">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/148/148838.svg" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="sphere__title">
      Здоровье
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sphere intelligence">
     <div class="svg__icon">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1491/1491214.svg" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="sphere__title">
      Развитие
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sphere sociality">
     <div class="svg__icon">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1078/1078011.svg" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="sphere__title">
      Отношения
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>  <!-- .spheres -->
  </div> <!-- .container -->

  <div class="container fluid">
   <div class="add">
    <div class="add__title">
     Добавить задачу
    </div>
    <div class="add__input-wrapper">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Бег 1 км" class="add__input">
     <div class="add__button"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> <!-- .container.fluid -->

  <div class="container">
   <div class="tasks">
    <div class="task" data-id="0" data-listener='false'>
     <div class="task__close"></div>
     Моя первая задача
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> <!-- .container -->
 
 </section>

</body>
</html>
```